# Como fixar uma string pelo seu index de forma que fique alinhado no print?

Tags: python, string, índices

Estou tendo um complicações em imprimir meu código, basicamente eu gostaria de "travar" a frase: "vida de" para sempre começar em um index fixo depois dos "█", porém não estou conseguindo aplicar isso no meu print, ela está acompanhando o simbolo "█", de maneira que ela não fica alinhada com o primeiro impressão no terminal, vocês poderiam me ajudar?

```
modulo_new1 = {"vida": 10}

print(f"""Modulo 1: \033[:31m{"█"*modulo_new1["vida"]}\033[m vida de {modulo_new1["vida"]} """)
modulo_new1["vida"] -= 3
print(f"""Modulo 1: \033[:31m{"█"*modulo_new1["vida"]}\033[m vida de {modulo_new1["vida"]} """)

Terminal: 
Modulo 1: ██████████ vida de 10 
Modulo 1: ███████ vida de 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já que está usando o formato f'string, recomendo ler este post [docstrings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Apos a sua expressao `{"█"*modulo_new1["vida"]` , adicione `: <20}` , assim voce alinhará a expressao ao lado esquerdo < e insirá a expressao seguinte apos vinte caracteres.

```
< alinhamento na esquerda
> alinhamento na direita
^ alinhamento central
```

Se utilizar uma variável, lembre_se de utilizar as chaves. Aqui a resposta da sua pergunta com um exemplo:

```
vida_total=20
modulo_new1 = {"vida": 10}


print(f"""Modulo 1: \033[:31m{"█"*modulo_new1["vida"] : <{vida_total}}\033[m vida de {modulo_new1["vida"]} """)
modulo_new1["vida"] -= 3
print(f"""Modulo 1: \033[:31m{"█"*modulo_new1["vida"] : <{vida_total}}\033[m vida de {modulo_new1["vida"]} """)
```

Espero ter ajudado.